# calculate free disk space percentage powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get the free percentage like present in Disk Management

```
$Diskmgmt = Get-Volume | select DriveLetter,FileSystemLabel,FileSystem,DriveType,HealthStatus,OperationalStatus,SizeRemaining,Size

foreach($dsk in $Diskmgmt)
{

    $dl = $dsk.DriveLetter
    $fsl = $dsk.FileSystemLabel
    $fs = $dsk.FileSystem
    $dt = $dsk.DriveType
    $hs = $dsk.HealthStatus
    $os = $dsk.OperationalStatus
    $sizer = [math]::round($dsk.SizeRemaining /1Gb, 2)
    $siz = [math]::round($dsk.Size /1Gb, 2)
    $PercentFree =  [Math]::Round(($sizer / $siz) * 100, 2)
```

but the calculation coming like below

```
Capacity     Free Space %Free
154.82 GB     200 GB     77 % 
0 GB          0 GB       77 % 
1.96 GB       6 GB       33 % 
0.15 GB       0.49 GB    31 % 
52.32 GB      99.51 GB   53 % 
11.19 GB      11.23 GB   100 % 
9.95 GB       10 GB      99 %
```

Please let me know if I am doing it correctly.

Comment: As you've currently consistently got more free space than there is capacity, for starters, the column headers are probably the wrong way round. Second, you don't want to round either number before dividing, that just introduces inaccuracy. Third, you should look at what your loop is doing (presumably it's a loop) when a division by zero happens (empty capacity because there's no disk in the drive).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing you're looking for something like this:

```
$props = @(
    'DriveLetter'
    'FileSystemLabel'
    'FileSystem'
    'DriveType'
    'HealthStatus'
    'OperationalStatus'
    @{
        Name = 'SizeRemaining'
        Expression = { "{0:N3} Gb" -f ($_.SizeRemaining/ 1Gb) }
    }
    @{
        Name = 'Size'
        Expression = { "{0:N3} Gb" -f ($_.Size / 1Gb) }
    }
    @{
        Name = '% Free'
        Expression = { "{0:P}" -f ($_.SizeRemaining / $_.Size) }
    }
)

Get-Volume -DriveLetter C, D | Select-Object $props | Format-Table
```

As an example this is how it looks on my laptop for Drives `C` and `D`:

```
DriveLetter FileSystemLabel FileSystem DriveType HealthStatus OperationalStatus SizeRemaining Size       % Free
----------- --------------- ---------- --------- ------------ ----------------- ------------- ----       ------
          D                 NTFS       Fixed     Healthy      OK                748.731 Gb    931.512 Gb 80.38%
          C                 NTFS       Fixed     Healthy      OK                170.959 Gb    236.764 Gb 72.21%
```

Answer (score 1):

Using get-psdrive and the 'p' format specifier:

```
get-psdrive c | % { $_.free/($_.used + $_.free) } | % tostring p

9.24%
```

Comment: I am not sure I have to get other details also. updates my question

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I use:

```
$serverlist = "SERVER1","SERVER2","SERVER3"
$spaceObjects = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $serverList {Get-PSDrive | Where {$_.Name -eq 'E'}}
$spaceObjects | Select-Object -Property PSComputerName, Root, @{Label='Used (GB)'; expression={($_.Used/1GB).ToString('F2')}}, @{Label='Free (GB)'; expression={($_.Free/1GB).ToString('F2')}}, @{Label='% Free)'; expression={($_.Free/($_.Used + $_.Free)).ToString('P')}} | Format-Table
```

Output looks like this:

```
PSComputerName Root Used (GB) Free (GB) % Free)
-------------- ---- --------- --------- ------- 
SERVER1        E:\  4558.01   1061.86   18.89% 
SERVER2        E:\  4218.73   1401.15   24.93% 
SERVER3        E:\  1841.66   206.22    10.07%
```