# Want to get the Output as Percent to compare it easily with Get-PSDrive in Python

Tags: python, windows, powershell, devops, new-psdrive

I want to get the Used (GB) & the Free(GB) from a partition to compare it for monitoring, i have a script.

```
import winrm
s = winrm.Session('ipadress', auth=('Name', 'password')) command = "Get-PSDrive | Where {$_.Free}" r = s.run_ps(command) result = r.std_out converted = str(result, encoding='utf-8', errors='errors') print(converted)
```

the Output is this:

```
Name           Used (GB)     Free (GB) Provider      Root
----           ---------     --------- --------      ----
C                  63.25         26.15 FileSystem    C:\
```

I Want to get the % from the free space or the used space as a float to compare this value.

Comment: You can use a calculated property to calculate the free percent ... [calculate free disk space percentage powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69713066)

Comment: Try : command = "Get-PSDrive | Where {$_.Free} | foreach { $row = $_; $row | Add-Member -NotePropertyName percentage -NotePropertyValue ( 100 * ($_.'Free (GB)'/$_.'User (GB)'))}"

Comment: Maybe `Get-PSDrive | Where {$_.Free} | Select-Object Name, Root, @{n='free %'; e={100 *$_.Free /($_.Free +$_.Used)}}`? See [about_Calculated_Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties)…